# React- select Multi select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-select

I am new to react. I am working with react -select and am just displaying the values that the user inputs through the map function.

Here is the code:

```
const Departments = [
  { label: "OneIT", value: "OneIT" },
  { label: "HR", value: "HR" },
  { label: "Vigilance", value: "Vigilance" },
  { label: "Ethics", value: "Ethics" },
  { label: "Corporate Services", value: "Corporate Services" },
  { label: "Legal", value: "Legal" },
  { label: "Sports", value: "Sports" },
  { label: "TQM", value: "TQM" },
  { label: "Iron Making", value: "Iron Making" },
  { label: "TMH", value: "TMH" }
];

class MultiSelect2 extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOptions: []
  };
  handleChangeField = selectedOptions => {
    this.setState({ selectedOptions });
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-2"></div>
          <div className="col-md-8">
            <span>Select Department</span>
            <Select
              value={selectedOption}
              options={Departments}
              onChange={this.handleChangeField}
              isMulti
            />
            {this.state.selectedOptions.map(o => (
              <p>{o.value}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using the map function just to display the elements on the screen. What I wanted to do is to use this to store the elements in the array to pass all the values somewhere to the back end or for display in another class. How can I do this?

Comment: You've already got the items in `selectedOptions` array in your state, what do you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to may be store it in an element or variable so that I can so that I can move it to another class or the backend db. When I put selected options in another class the elements do not show

Comment: You can pass `selectedOption` as a prop to another component, put it in your state is correct. you can then do with this whatever you want

Comment: I did that. I added   state = {
    selectedOptions: []
  };

Comment: and added  const {
      values: { selectedOptions
      }
    } = this.props;
and then tried to add this into a list  <ListItemText
              primary="Departments"
              secondary={selectedOptions}
             
            />

but nothing is displayed

Comment: show this part in your code

Comment: what do you mean by show this part in your code?

Comment: show the code of `ListItemText` component